# How can I do an SQL pivot putting all results in 1 row per record?

Tags: sql, pivot

I have a table with a list of Customers (just their IDs) in one column, and then a list of Artists they like in another column, for example;

```
12345 Creed
12345 Evanescence
12345 Linkin Park
22556 Creed
22556 Foo Fighters
33485 Foo Fighters
```

I have created a Pivot using dynamic column headers (for the Artist) as although there is a set list for them to pick from, this could change and I don't want to have to keep updating the code every time there is a change (I want an easy life like the rest of us!)

What I want the Pivot to display is 1 row per Customer, to show which Artists they like.

However when I run the below PIVOT the results return more than 1 row per Customer for those Customers that have listed more than 1 Artist, like this:

```
CustomerID  Creed  Evanescence  Foo Fighters  Linkin Park
12345       Creed
12345              Evanescence
12345                                         Linkin Park
22556       Creed
22556                           Foo Fighters
33485                           Foo Fighters
```

What I want:

```
CustomerID  Creed  Evanescence  Foo Fighters  Linkin Park
12345       Creed  Evanescence                Linkin Park
22556       Creed               Foo Fighters
33485                           Foo Fighters
```

T-SQL

```
--Declare variables 
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
       + QUOTENAME([Artist])
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Artist] FROM ##TEMP_CustomerWithArtists) AS Artists

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID, ' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM ##TEMP_CustomerWithArtists
    PIVOT(MAX(Artist) 
          FOR [Artist] IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'
--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

Comment: With your Query I get the same expected result you have mentioned ? I assume it is Sql server.. Your query seems to work as expected

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2014 Management Studio and yes when I have just these 2 columns in the Table, the Queries work fine - sorry, I should have included all columns that existed in the Table as these were causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SELECT DISTINCT` is not needed in the outer query.

This problem occurs when the underlying table has additional columns.  You don't mention any, but try this:

```
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = N'
SELECT CustomerID, ' + @ColumnName + '
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID, Artist
      FROM ##TEMP_CustomerWithArtists cwa
     ) cwa
PIVOT(MAX(Artist) 
      FOR [Artist] IN (' + @ColumnName + ')
     ) AS PVTTable';
```

This behavior is one of the reasons I don't like the `PIVOT` syntax.

Comment: You're right, I should have included all columns that existed in the Table. Apologies.  Your solution has worked, which is for me to specify the 2 columns I need for the Pivot from the Table. Thank you for knowing exactly what I'd missed out and for providing the solution.